# How to bypass print-method

Tags: clojure, multimethod

I have an application with a lot of large maps and other things, which are clumsy to read when printed, so I made a custom print function for them and set up `print-method` to call it, like this:

```
(defmethod print-method clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap [v ^java.io.Writer w]
  (.write w (fstr1 v)))
```

Inside `fstr1`, how can I call the ordinary print-method if I determine that the map is not one of the kinds that require special treatment?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42933871/1393162) suggests putting a `:type` in the metadata, since `print-method` dispatches on that. I've had some success with that, but I can't always control the metadata, so I'm hoping there's a way to "forward" to the previously defined print-method from within `fstr1`.

---

For reference, here's my current implementation of `fstr1`:

```
(defn fstr1 ^String [x]
  (cond
    (ubergraph? x)
      (fstr-ubergraph x)
    (map? x)
      (case (:type x)
        :move (fstr-move x)
        :workspace "(a workspace)"
        :bdx (fstr-bdx x)
        :rxn (fstr-rxn x)
        (apply str (strip-type x)))
    :else
      (apply str (strip-type x))))
```

Comment: before investigating an alternative solution - have you tried `(set! *print-length* 10)`

Answer (score 2):

You can always rebind `print-object` and tuck the real `print-object` away so you can call it when appropriate:

```
user> (let [real-print-method print-method]
        (with-redefs [print-method (fn [v w]
                                     (if (and (map? v)
                                              (:foo v))
                                       (do
                                         (real-print-method "{:foo " w)
                                         (real-print-method (:foo v) w)
                                         (real-print-method " ...}" w))
                                       (real-print-method v w)))]
          (println {:foo 42 :bar 23} {:baz 11 :quux 0})))
{:foo 42 ...} {:baz 11, :quux 0}
nil
user>
```